# How to add new content to my flutter app on the fly?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, flutter

My flutter app provides some content (mostly text and graphics, like blog posts, or news) to its users. These contents need to be updated daily. So there will be new texts, images, maybe even videos. Now, the app would be used even when offline, so all the updated contents should be stored somewhere to be accessed later.

- Right now, I'm using a SQLite DB to store texts
- The images are stored in the Assets folder of the app.
- The nature of the program is such that the users won't want to give the app any SD-Card access permission.

**So my question is, how can I update the content without *updating the whole app* or using any SDcard permissions?**

Is it possible to write code that downloads the new content and saves them directly in the Assets folder of the app? Can the app then use the files? without them being referenced in *"pubspec.YAML"* file?

Can I store all the data (even images and videos which are added daily) in my SQLite DB which is located in phone memory?

What is the standard practice for apps that have this kind of content?

Comment: You'll need access to some sort of local storage to store the binary of your images. You can't dynamically add assets to your app, as they are bundled inside the APK

Comment: @Remi So, the Assets folder is write protected? I thought if it was possible to automatically download and save new content in that folder, then I could use an "Image.Asset('filepath') widget to show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the storage somehow.

In Android, you don't have to ask for storage permission if you want to save data in internal directory for your app which is   `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/data/your_package_name/` folder. You can try that.

However it has got a downside, if your app is deleted then all the data will also be deleted.

Comment: Can I load that data (e.g image) in my app then? Or it needs to be explicitly referenced as an asset in my "pubspec.yaml" file?

Comment: Yes, of course you can load the data in your app. You don't have to reference anything like that in your pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: What happens if the app is updated (user downloads update, installs newer version APK) ?  Does an update delete that folder and all of its contents?

Comment: If user deletes the app, everything stored will also be deleted. When user installs the app first time, the folder will be created where you can place your data and when user updates the app, this folder still exist and you have old data plus you can perform any function like you could perform before.